# Verilog counter stuck at 48

Tags: verilog, counter, vivado

For part of my VGA signaling module, I've had to make a specific horizontal counter and vertical counter to a keep count the pixels. I've been stuck on these counters because they don't get past 48 for some reason when simulating the code in vivado. My code for the horizontal counter:

```
module horizontal_counter#(
    parameter LIM = 800, //horizontal counter counts from 0-799
    parameter N = $clog2(LIM) + 1 //amount of bits we have to count
    )
    (
    input wire iClk, iRst, 
    output wire [N-1:0] oCountH 
    );
    reg [N-1:0] r_CntCurr; 
    wire [N-1:0] w_CntNext; 

    always @(posedge iClk)
    begin
        if(iRst == 1)
            r_CntCurr <= 0;
           else 
            r_CntCurr <= w_CntNext;
     end 
     //checking the limit and counter, if we reached limit we go to zero if we didnt reach the limit we add one more
     assign  w_CntNext = (r_CntCurr != LIM) ? r_CntCurr + 1: 0;
     //assign the output 
     assign oCountH = r_CntCurr; 

endmodule
```

My testbench was the following:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1fs
module horizontal_counter_TB;
    
    //signal declaration
    localparam N_inst = $clog2(800) + 1;
    reg  r_iClk, r_iRst;
    wire [N_inst-1:0] w_oCountH;
  
    horizontal_counter #(.N(N_inst)) horizontal_counter_inst( .iClk(r_iClk), .iRst(r_iRst), .oCountH(w_oCountH));
    
    //generating clock signal
    localparam T=20;
     
    always begin
        r_iClk = 1;
        #(T/2);
        r_iClk = 0;
        #(T/2);
    end 
    
    //stimulus generator
    initial
    begin
    r_iRst = 1;
    #50;
    r_iRst = 0;
    
    //voor 100 cylci
    #(100*T);
    $stop;
    end     
endmodule
```

At first I thought I had made an error with the amount of bits or my code itself, but I didn't find it. When simulating with lower limits under 48, the code works perfectly fine, but 48 seems to be the devil's number. I did realize that 48 in binary is 110000, but the code should allow me to count from 0-10 which should be 11 bits, enough to count until 800.

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe the line parameter N = $clog2(LIM) + 1 is not getting simulated properly. Can you input parameter = 12; and try again?

Comment: @blackblade with values under 48 it always works, when I go over 48 it does not work. So I don't think the error is there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a syntax error in the testbench code that you posted.  The `always` block needs a `begin` keyword:

```
always begin
    r_iClk = 1;
    #(T/2);
    r_iClk = 0;
    #(T/2);
end
```

If that is really the code you ran, it is surprising that vivado did not give you a compile error.

The testbench also stops the simulation after only 2000ns, which does not allow the counter to reach the value of 800.  You can delete these lines to see the counter hit 800 and roll over to 0:

```
#(100*T);
$stop;
```

Or, you could increase `100*T` to at least `800*T`.

Here is a working example on [EDA Playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/GzjU).  It uses `900*T`.  In waveforms, you can see `w_oCountH` hits 0x320 (800) at about time=16,000ns.

Comment: I did have the begin keyword, accidentally deleted it while copying my lines, my bad :(. Thanks for the tip on the bottom line though but even when changing that my counter waveform doesn't go past 47. (deleting or changing it, still doesn't go past 47.)

Comment: A better way to simulate clock would be: always #(T/2) clk = ~clk; Also, you need not necessarily include $finish directive. And make sure to increase simulation time from the settings.

Comment: @Sydon: I updated my answer with a link to edaplayground, where you can run the updated code and see the counter hit 800.

Comment: @blackblade thanks alot for the edaplayground link and yeah I did see it hit 800, I suppose I have to change my vivado settings to make it run long enough.  Why is #(T/2) clk = ~clk; a better way to generate a clock signal?

Comment: @blackblade: With many simulators, `$finish` is required to end the simulation; I don't use vivado, so maybe that is not the case with that simulator.  "increase simulation time from the settings"  : perhaps you are referring specifically to vivado setup.

Comment: @Sydon Because you have effectively reduced 4 lines of code to a single line, not to mention easier to interpret.

Comment: @toolic Yes, becuase OP is also using Vivado it seems.

Comment: @Sydon: I posted the link to edaplayground not blackblade.

Comment: @toolic Ah my bad, I was in quite a hurry. Thanks alot!

Comment: @blackblade: comments are not intended for performing code style reviews. You are free to post your own answer to include such information. I will now flag all these comments for removal by a Moderator since comments are not intended for discussions.

Comment: @Sydon: You're welcome.

Answer (score 3):

As @toolic pointed, there was minor issue in your testbench. Use the following testbench and increase simulation time to 5000ns.

```
`timescale 1ns / 1fs
module horizontal_counter_TB;
    
    //signal declaration
    localparam N_inst = $clog2(800) + 1;
    reg  r_iClk, r_iRst;
    wire [N_inst-1:0] w_oCountH;
  
    horizontal_counter #(.N(N_inst)) horizontal_counter_inst( .iClk(r_iClk), .iRst(r_iRst), .oCountH(w_oCountH));
    
    //generating clock signal
    localparam T=20;
     
    always #(T/2) r_iClk = ~r_iClk;
    
    //stimulus generator
    initial
    begin
    r_iClk = 0;
    r_iRst = 1;
    #50;
    r_iRst = 0;
    
    #5000 $finish;
    end     
endmodule
```

Comment: It's just for simulation purpose